# Matching strings between two characters

Tags: python, regex

I answered a question the other day about finding the strings that occur between two specified characters.  I ended up with this fairly basic regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> def smallest_between_two(a, b, text):
...     return re.findall(re.escape(a) + "(.*?)" + re.escape(b), text)
...
>>> smallest_between_two(' ', '(', 'def test()')
['test']
>>> smallest_between_two('[', ']', '[this one][this one too]')
['this one', 'this one too']
>>> smallest_between_two('paste ', '/', '@paste "game_01/01"')
['"game_01']
```

However, when I went to look over it again, I realized that there was a common error that could occur when a match was partially contained inside of another match.  Here is an example:

```
>>> smallest_between_two(' ', '(', 'here is an example()')
['is an example']
```

I am unsure of why it is not also finding `an example`, and `example`, as both of those also occur between a `' '` and a `'('`

I would rather not do this to find additional matches:

```
>>> first_iteration = smallest_between_two(' ', '(', 'here is an example()')
>>> smallest_between_two(' ', '(', first_iteration[0] + '(')
['an example']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for *overlapping* regex matching. Simply put, this is not easy to do with the default regex engine in python.

You can, however, use the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (`pip install` it first). Call `regex.findall` and set `overlapped=True`.

```
import regex 

a, b = ' ', '('
text = 'here is an example()'

regex.findall('{}(.*?){}'.format(*map(re.escape, (a, b))), text, overlapped=True)
['is an example', 'an example', 'example']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna explain why your one worked like that. For an overlapped matching, please see [the answer already provided by cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846911/3789550) using the `regex` module's `findall` method with `overlapped=True` keyword argument.

---

Your one matches like that because the space at the Regex pattern start, matches the *first* space in the input, and then the non-greedy quantifier `.*?` matches the minimal between that space and next `(`. So, it is operating correctly. To better understand it, make the input string `here is an example()another example()`.

Now, to get the shortest match in this case, you can use the zero-with negative lookahead to ensure that there is no space in between:

```
 (?!.* )(.*?)\(
```

So:

```
In [81]: re.findall(r' (?!.* )(.*?)\(', 'here is an example()')
Out[81]: ['example']
```